# make one div wrap around another div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've got a div containing two divs. One is an image with - values for top and left to make it sit on the top edge like a legend. But the div next to it just keeps it in one column to the left. Really, I want the text to wrap around, as to fill all the purple space. Here's what I've got:

```
//jsfiddle.net/ucfnL0px/1/embed/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put you image inside your `div.CornPara` and set it to `float: left;` and the text will wrap around it.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucfnL0px/4/)

HTML

```
<div class="ServContent">   
   <div class="CornPara">
       <img class="corner" src="#" />
       <h1 class="SubServ">Lorem</h1>
       ...More content...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img.corner {
  ...
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be easy.

Just put the image inside the "CornPara" div, set it to float: left and use negative margin instead position relative.

Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/hmsh0x0z/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ServContent">
 <div class="CornPara">
  <img class="corner" src="#" />
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img.corner {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Also upvoting this suggestion one as the use of margin-left, right etc was useful for a follow up question about removing the spacing around the image.